# Why is $friend not being expanded in FQL JSON query?

Tags: php, string, quotes

I'm trying to setup a multiquery in FQL in PHP, with a variable. But I can't seem to get it to work correctly

```
  $fql = '{
        "uid"   : "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = \"$friend\"",
        "album": "SELECT object_id, link, aid, cover_pid, location, name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM #uid)",
        "photo": "SELECT src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #album)"
    }';
```

This is basically trying to get the cover photos of your friends album.

If I put in a friend's username directly in place of $friend, I get all the results, but not with the above code where $friend is dynamically set.

What went wrong!!??
Thanks

Comment: Note that the outside quotes are `'`s and *not* `"`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings using single quotes are not evaluated by PHP. In this case you should concatenate them using the dot operator:

```
$fql = '{
        "uid"   : "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = \"' . $friend . '\"",
        "album": "SELECT object_id, link, aid, cover_pid, location, name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM #uid)",
        "photo": "SELECT src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #album)"
    }';
```

You should take a look at [the "PHP bible"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, variables inside of double quoted strings will be evaluated, while variables inside of single quoted strings will not.

Your best solution is to reverse the quotes so your string looks like this:

```
$fql = "{
    'uid'   : 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = '$friend',
    'album': 'SELECT object_id, link, aid, cover_pid, location, name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM #uid)',
    'photo': 'SELECT src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #album)'
}";
```

This will cause `$friend` to be evaluated to the value of your variable.

Comment: This isn't quite valid. The generated JSON is bonkered around `'$friend'` due to unbalanced quotes and "clobbered" quotes. Likely just want to suck it up and use `\"` or a here-doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "85";
print "The number is: ".$text.".";
```

this will output:

```
The number is: 85.
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL usually all varchar are between single quotes instead of double
Have you tried this?

```
"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = '" . $friend . "'",
```

Comment: This still won't work. The entire JSON is a string (and single quoted in this case).